# override/redirect file calls from JNI or NDK

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, smartcard

I have a Smart card, that was delivered with a properitary, precompiled JNI/NDK library.

The smart card works by having the end user app access a file in the root of the SD card.

This works by having the end user app read/write APDU's to a interface in the JNI library, the JNI library translates those APDU's to writes and reads to the file.

The specification of how APDU's are read/written to this file are properitary and not available to the customers of the card.

Now to the problem:
Since the new Android 4.4.2 SD card policy prevents writes to the SD card except for the app userspace folder, its not possible to write to the SD card root, and thus the function of the SD SmartCard is lost.

However, if you use a OPEN_DOCUMENT intent and a file picker in the end user app, you could have the end user select the relevant file in the root of SD card, and thus gain r/w permission to this file through a file descriptor.

However, I wonder, is it possible to redirect/override all outgoing file calls (read/writes) from a precompiled JNI library, to instead go through the file descriptor returned by the intent?

Eg if I could in some way "override" the raw file open method called by any libraries (some proprietary .so files) loaded by my app, to go through my app and then I dont open the file, instead I just pass the "OPEN_DOCUMENT" file descriptor directly, so the .so files are Reading/Writing from this file descriptor, that are actually returned by the OPEN_DOCUMENT intent, gaining access to the file in the root of the SD card that is used for APDU Communication with the smart card.

Comment: Is the smart card library static or shared?

Comment: @AlexCohn: You thinking `LD_PRELOAD`?  (We used to use that for the Android simulator -- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/gingerbread/simulator/wrapsim/ )

Comment: I'm not being helpful now but it seems to me the easiest way to fix this is to get new version of the library from smartcard vendor. Doesn't he support Android 4.4.2? Because he would have to deal with this problem and fix it in less hackish way.

Comment: Its static, since the code for Calling the library is: static { system.loadLibrary("libraryname"); }. However, this static library is loaded by a JAR, that is in turn loaded by my app. So the best way here is if I could "Catch" all attempts to open a file downstream in my app. So if my app com.test.appname loads somejni.jar that in turn load somelibrary.so, I want to have code in com.test.appname that Catch all attempts for somejni.jar and somelibrary.so to open a file. It doesn't matter if it Catch open attempts by itself (com.test.appname) too, since I will never open a file in my app anyway

Comment: If their library is loaded directly from your Java, it is a [shared library](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/linux-shared-libraries/). It is [possible](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) to manipulate this `so` file so that instead of calling `open()` from **/system/lib/libc.so** it will call `specialopen()` in a shared library that you prepare, which connects to Java to receive the file descriptor. I dare say, the task as you define it, is not impossible, but requires deep understanding and high technical skills.

Comment: @fadden: I would rather "massage" the 3rd party lib, to call my function instead of `open()`. What do you think about that?

Comment: @AlexCohn: so long as your new function has the same number of characters (so you can hex-edit in place), it seems like it should work.